# BitmapData pattern fill in actionscript 3.0

Tags: image, actionscript-3, drawing, fill, bitmapdata

How do i fill some BitmapData image with other image pattern in as 3.0? For example, i have an white image with black square at the center which would be "square:BitmapData" and the other image with little(2x2) blue circle which i would call "circle:BitmapData". I want to fill that square with this blue circles, is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Here i found the example of what i need to do:

*This is two images (left is like my square, right is like the blue circle)*
http://pix.samoucka.ru/img/content/graphics/thewebschedule/8/466.gif

*And this is how it would look after filling*
http://pix.samoucka.ru/img/content/graphics/thewebschedule/8/467.gif

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`copyPixels()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29) and iterating though x and y to tile the whole thing, `copyPixels()` is very fast.

Or

It might be simpler to create a Sprite and use [`graphics.beginBitmapFill()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginBitmapFill%28%29) then `graphics.drawRect()` with the correct size, then `draw()` to the BitmapData in the correct position.

If you need to determine the size and position of the black square, `getColorBoundsRect()` should do the job.

Comment: I read your answer again and if i understand right this is what the getColorBoundsRect() is for. So i would need to use it to get the similar color rectangle area that i would need to fill, right?

Comment: looking at your update the example you provide is more complicated then what i thought, my suggestion will only fill rectangles.

Comment: getColorBoundsRect() expects a color and returns the bounding box that encapsulates ALL the pixels of that color in the bitmap i.e. a Rectangle object containing x,y,width and height.